# How to get cover video url from Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Currently, even if I have a video on my cover, when I request `{page_id}?fields=cover`, the url is still image instead of video. So I'm wondering how to get Facebook cover video url using graph api? Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw, did you check out the docs already? what do they say about it?

Comment: @luschn You're right, it's not that related to node just that I'm using node. I've checked the doc and it didn't say anything about cover video, only cover photo. Inside `{page_id}?fields=videos` though, I'm able to get a list of videos in my page but there's no way to tell which is my cover one.

Comment: Is `featured_video` something different than the cover video? (Can’t test right now.)